# Tensorflow 2.0: How are metrics computed when the ouput is sequential?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have been working with binary sequential inputs and outputs using Tensorflow 2.0, and I've been wondering which approach Tensorflow uses to compute metrics such as recall or accuracy during training in those scenarios.

Each sample to my network consists of 60 timesteps, each with 300 features, and thus my expected output is a `(60, 1)` array of 1s and 0s. Suppose I have 2000 validation samples. When evaluating the validation   set for each epoch, does tensorflow concatenates *all* of the 2000 samples into a single `(2000*60=120000, 1)` array and then compares to the concatenated groundtruth labels, or does it evalutes each of the `(60, 1)` individually and then returns a mean of those values? Is there any way to modify this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tensorflow/Keras by default computes the metrics batch-wise for train data, while it computes the same metrics on ALL the data passed in `validation_data` parameters in `fit` method.

This means that the metric printed during fitting for the train data is the mean of that score calculated on all the batches. In other words, for trainset keras evaluates each bach individually and then returns a mean of those values. For validation data is different, keras gets all the validation samples and then compares them with the "concatenated" groundtruth labels.

To prove this behavior with code I propose a dummy example. I provide a custom callback that computes for sure the accuracy score on ALL the data passed at the end of the epoch (for train and optionally validation). this is useful for us to understand the behavior of tensorflow during training.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import *

class ACC_custom(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def __init__(self, train, validation=None):
        super(ACC_custom, self).__init__()
        self.validation = validation
        self.train = train

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):

        logs['ACC_score_train'] = float('-inf')
        X_train, y_train = self.train[0], self.train[1]
        y_pred = (self.model.predict(X_train).ravel()>0.5)+0
        score = accuracy_score(y_train.ravel(), y_pred)       

        if (self.validation):
            logs['ACC_score_val'] = float('-inf')
            X_valid, y_valid = self.validation[0], self.validation[1]
            y_val_pred = (self.model.predict(X_valid).ravel()>0.5)+0
            val_score = accuracy_score(y_valid.ravel(), y_val_pred)
            logs['ACC_score_train'] = np.round(score, 5)
            logs['ACC_score_val'] = np.round(val_score, 5)
        else:
            logs['ACC_score_train'] = np.round(score, 5)
```

create dummy data

```
x_train = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1000,60,10))
y_train = np.random.randint(0,2, (1000,60,1))

x_val = np.random.uniform(0,1, (500,60,10))
y_val = np.random.randint(0,2, (500,60,1))
```

fit model

```
inp = Input(shape=((60,10)), dtype='float32')
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(inp)
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inp, out)

es = EarlyStopping(patience=10, verbose=1, min_delta=0.001, 
                   monitor='ACC_score_val', mode='max', restore_best_weights=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=10, verbose=2,
          callbacks=[ACC_custom(train=(x_train,y_train),validation=(x_val,y_val)),es],
          validation_data=(x_val,y_val))
```

in the graphs below I make a comparison between the accuracies computed by our callback and the accuracy computed by keras

```
plt.plot(history.history['ACC_score_train'], label='accuracy_callback_train')
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='accuracy_default_train')
plt.legend(); plt.title('train accuracy')
```

[image]

```
plt.plot(history.history['ACC_score_val'], label='accuracy_callback_valid')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label='accuracy_default_valid')
plt.legend(); plt.title('validation accuracy')
```

[image]

as we can see the accuracy on the train data (first plot) is different between the default method and our callbacks. this means that the accuracy of train data is calculated batch-wise.
the validation accuracy (second plot) calculated by our callback and the default method is the same! this means that the score on validation data is computed one-shoot